# Ajax request triggers submit.... why?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

So I have something that might seem a little bitty but here goes.

This is all done using jQuery

I have a function "cont_refresh" I use for refreshing page content and the like which contains an AJAX request for passing variables to an external document/script for processing.

In addition to this, I have an anonymous function that shold be triggered on the form submit... which is meant to be completely unrelated and should not happen on this button press.

However at some point when I run "cont_refresh" the submit function is triggered, the point in which it appears to trigger the submit function is when I get to making my ajax request.

What ends up happening is I make to ajax requests, the one intended which just runs a function on the server and the second which is to submit my form... I don't want the latter to happen.

There are two buttons to handle both these things separately, one is a submit button the other, related to this issue is not a submit button.

**Why? and how do I prevent this?**

There will be question whirling around your heads as to why this buffoon has two functions that basically do the same thing but that is for another topic for which I would gracefully request you raise a new post for ;).

```js
/*
  This is what I want to run... it does but fails then.....(see below this function)
*/
function cont_refresh(form,params,url,e,modal){
    $(".ng-loading-container").toggleClass("ng-loading-container-show");
   
    if(modal === 'undefined'){
        modal = false;
    }
    var request = $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: params,
        success: function(result){
            
          if(e !== '' && e !== 'undefined'){
                $(e).html(result);    
            } else {
                alert('Success');
            }
            
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Page Error')
            $(".ng-loading-container").toggleClass("ng-loading-container-show");
        },
        }).fail(function() {
            alert( "Something went wrong!" );
            $(".ng-loading-container").toggleClass("ng-loading-container-show");
        })
    // end of cont_refresh()
}

/*
.... This runs. Which is not my intention!
*/

$('form').submit(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    submit_form(e.target);
    // there is an additional function that handles any submition from this point but have not included it as .
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Rightly or wrongly the intention here is to run a stored SQL procudure.<br>
<p>The reason the statements are stored in the db is so anyone (with access) can add and edit these statements or functions from my front end application.</p>

<form role="form" action="myscript.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="stp_tsk_id" id="stp_tsk_id" class="form-control" value="34">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label for="stp_function">Function (SQL statement)</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="stp_function" id="stp_function" rows="3">SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE</textarea>
</div>
<!-- this button should trigger only the function it is calling onclick -->
<button role="button" 
        class="btn btn-default btn-md"
        onclick="cont_refresh('',{'id':34},'app/handlers/process_steps.php')">
                Run this Step
        </button> 
  
 <!-- There is a second "submit" button but not relevent for this query -->
  <button role="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-md">Save</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: use e.preventDefault(); where e is the event handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer relates to the buttons.

I did not realize that by using a HTML5 button I needed to specify a type of button to prevent default action of submit.

```
<button>This will Submit</button>
<button type="button">Will not Submit</button>
```

I thank @TimBrownlaw & @Nitin for guiding me to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you could try this...

Give your form an id like

```
<form role="form" action="myscript.php" method="post" id="myForm">
```

But please feel free to be more creative with the id name...

And change your event to

```
$('#myForm').submit(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    submit_form(e.target);
    // there is an additional function that handles any submition from this point but have not included it as .
});
```

And see if that helps.

Comment: There are many forms this function deals with so I do not want to specify a form name. This function works perfectly, the problem is, it should not be triggered in this event.

I can see I was not entirely clear in my question but the cont_refresh function is what I want to trigger. I do trigger that but when it gets to the ajax call, the global submit function is triggered, Don't understand why.

Comment: Well I was kinda going for, if you were to try it, does the issue go away which is in reference to what @Nitin suggested in his answer. At least that may help see what is happening.

Comment: So what this showed me is even though the button is not a submit button it is indeed submitting my form.

Comment: Ok so what if you alter your button to include type="button" in its declaration. That should stop it defaulting to being a type="submit"

Comment: I have already, done and submitted it as an answer. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Good stuff Craig! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have added your form.submit function globally, which will obviously get called after page refresh i.e on page load.

Add your  **$('form').submit()** function on button click event or something else.

Your ajax is not submitting the form, itis getting submitted due to the global function  **$('form').submit()**

```
$('form').submit(function (e){  // instead of form use here button click event
    e.preventDefault();
    submit_form(e.target);
    // there is an additional function that handles any submition from         this point but have not included it as .
});
```

Comment: Not sure that is the case.

Comment: Not sure that is the case.... not entirely anyway?

The button is not a submit button so should not trigger the global submit action (as I understand it). The function I am calling is being triggered however it is also triggering the submit function when my function gets to the AJAX request.

On a side note, how do I delete my previous, incomplete comment?